# Find filename and modification date of file in folder

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to import data from an Excel file into Access automatically. I have a working script, the only issue is that the filename may change (the folder name won't) and I need to figure out how to:

1. Define a variable (filepath) that is equal to the URL of the only file in the destination folder
2. If there is more than one file, display a msgbox box ("Multiple files exist in destination folder, please remove obsolete file")

Can't find anything relevant. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work for you

```
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filepath = oFSo.GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Set myFolder = oFSo.GetFolder( filepath )

If myFolder.Files.Count > 1 Then

    MsgBox "Multiple Files exist in destination folder, please remove obsolete file"

Else

    for each myFile in myFolder.Files

        myFileName = myFile.Name

    next

    myFullFileName = filepath & "\" & myFileName    

End If
```

Comment: Thanks that is close, but how do I define a variable that is equal to the filepath+filename, so I can run the data import script

Comment: Ok I have modified the code just slightly to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Would advise you loop through the Dir function to count how many files there are. If only one, then return the Dir. If more, then display your messagebox.

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/file/dir.php